# How to move the outlook navbar back to the bottom of the page

Tags: outlook

There is a navbar on the left hand side of microsoft outlook. Highlighted here:

[image: Picture of navbar]

It used to be at the bottom left and in a horizontal position and I'd like to move it back.

How can I do this?

Edit: I will not close this question. It's highly relevant to the audience of this site. Attica! Attica! Attica! Why else would "outlook" be a valid tag?

Comment: I found [this](https://youtu.be/L59snh6bXbs), please verify (your version/up-to-date): File>Options>Advanced>Outlook panes> *uncheck* "Show Apps in Outlook"

Comment: @xerx593 That's the solution. Thanks Xerx. If you write that up as an answer then I'll approve it, just in case anyone else is looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 for the video :)

https://youtu.be/L59snh6bXbs

In text form:

1. Navigate to `File>Options>Advanced` tab
2. In `Outlook panes` section *uncheck* `Show Apps in Outlook` checkbox
3. Re-start outlook (to changes take effect)